# Samsung Smart TV SDK fastforward/rewind and playing hls playlist

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to play H L S video playlist in Samsung smart TV . the S D K i am using for development is 3.5.2 .  function i am using to ff/Rewind is

skipVideoSpeed(-2)

I am not able to get the duration of H L S video that i am playing . And

skipVideoSpeed()

is also not working during rewind . And i tried to find out a method to play video back to back in playlist when one video ends till last video in that playlist .but didn't get any solution . But i am able to play single video at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the video duration by using function `GetDuration()`

```
var totalTime=Player.GetDuration();
```

GetDuration() returns the total playing time if it succeed, otherwise return -1.

it is mentioned in the device api guide of Samsung
http://freethetv2011.s3.amazonaws.com/DeviceAPI_Guide%5BV2.20%5D%5B1%5D.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Also if you play live stream, in m3u8 file can be length too short (about 10s it depends on stream settings)

If you skip (currentTime + 10seconds) and getDuration returns too short time then stream finish.

I hope that it could help :)